# write MATLAB class in separate files

Tags: matlab, oop

It's nothing new to ask such question. Since I've spent some hours reading on the documentation and available examples. But awkwardly, MATLAB seems not accept my code. So, I feel totally confused

```
classdef testclass

    %UNTITLED Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        a =3;
        b =4;
    end

    methods

        function obj = testclass(a_inp, b_inp) % 
            obj.a = a_inp;
            obj.b = b_inp;
        end

        output = plus(obj)

        output = minus(obj)
    end

end
```

and the function

```
function output = minus(obj)

output = obj.a-obj.b;
end
```

I think this is a typical test. But when I initialize the class, it comes this error

```
Error using testclass
Too many input arguments.

Error in class_call (line 2)
myclass = testclass(3,4    );
```

I create the class by myclass = testclass(3,4    );

what might be wrong in my code? plz help! I'm stuck!

Comment: AFAIK I know, MATLAB has no concept of *partial classes* that can be spread across multiple m files. You'll have to define those methods in the same file, within the class definition.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html)? @Praetorian isn't correct. Either you define everything in one big file or you define everything based on the `@MyClass` folder scheme. The lines `output = plus(obj)` and `output = minus(obj)` in your classdef make no sense.

Comment: @horchler Thanks! It's been a while since I've looked at the OOP stuff in MATLAB and clearly I have some catching up to do.

Comment: thank you for your common interests in MATLAB OOP! @horchler: that's the signatures of the functions contained in separate files and it's mentioned in section "Specifying Method Attributes in classdef File" in your link

Comment: What is `class_call`? And why are there extra spaces after your `4`? are you changing what the real inputs are? I can't replicate this. Can you call `obj = testclass(3,4)` from the command window? Also, there's no need to include function signatures if you're not specifying any method attributes like `Static` or `Access=private` (I suppose it doesn't hurt but it looks weird).

Comment: the spaces are just typos!  thanks for the information about function signature! I tried and both works

Comment: I don't know what to conclude now. Now it runs!! without any modification from the folder nor files. Probably, you can try the code from M-file or command line

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is correct. As @ horchler says only thing you need is to put all your files including class definition inside @testclass directory. Without this directory you cannot have separate files for a class.

The code you tried for instantiating the class also should work fine outside @testclass directory. You would get error only when calling the method plus or minus if you have not placed your files in @testclass directory.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not my current mistake. In my folder @testclass, there are 3 .m files, testclass.m, plus.m and minus.m. but still comes the error originally mentioned